# Sum a Range and Format the Sum Error

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, sum, range

I have this bit of code that doesn't like to run:

```
Dim ConcTotal as Double

ConcTotal = Workbooks("MW_vs_RF.xls").Sheets(wbkTwo).Format$(Sum(Range("C4:C14")), "0.0000")
```

where wbkTwo is a specific tab in that xls sheet.  I am simply trying to sum a range in another sheet and assign it to ConcTotal.  Everytime I run this I get an error message saying "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined" and it highlights the "Sum" in my code above.  I do not see any issue with the code or how it is written, any help on why I am getting this error is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.Worksheetfuntion.Sum()` instead of `Sum()`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ConcTotal As Double
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks("MW_vs_RF.xls")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) '~~> For testing purpose, replaced `wbkTwo`
    Set rng = ws.Range("C4:C14")

    ConcTotal = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng), "0.0000")

    Debug.Print ConcTotal
End Sub
```

Comment: I have made the code more precise so that you can easily understand it. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: Yup, I am using `rng` which has already be declared. See the 3 Set commands.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to ask a new question :) Ask a separate question ;)